# What is Response Paging in Version 2 Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, aws-sdk

I am trying to parse describe_instances api's response from Aws::EC2::Client. But verion 2 of aws ruby sdk comes with response paging feature.

I dont understand what exactly is this!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't really a good question for Stack Overflow. Explaining how something works doesn't fit well into the question categories because it can generate a small book. Instead, you need to read their documentation carefully and follow any examples, and, if that doesn't help, consult their tech support who are better equipped to answer specific questions about their tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response paging is a feature where you can enumerate calls to an API, yielding one response as a time, until all results have been received. This can be **very** important for API calls that return a large amount of data, such as enumerating objects in a bucket in Amazon S3.

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
ec2.describe_instances.each do |response|
  # do something with the response
end
```

Without response paging you would have to do something like this:

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Client.new
token = nil
begin
  resp = ec2.describe_instances(next_token: nil)
  # do something with the response ...
  token = resp.next_token 
while token
```

Some APIs have more complex paging requirements. Response paging eliminates the need to understand the paging requirements of every API call, and provides an `#each` method on the response.